# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props = props') React-Native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Just started the project and sucked

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
export default class SignUp extends Component() {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>SignUp</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

stack navigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import SignUp from "../screens/SignUpScreen";

export default AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    SignUp: SignUp,
})
```

Getting this error:

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrwj9.png)

Comment: Is there any more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because you should write

```
export default class SignUp extends Component { ... }
```

Instead of

```
export default class SignUp extends Component() { ... }
```